# What is the subject of this sentence?

Tags: translation, song-lyrics

I'm translating a song which can be seen [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SUQV5g9QoUA). At the end of the song is this:

> 傷つけてしまう夜もあるだろう 分かち合えない想いもあるだろう

What is the subject of 傷つけてしまう夜もあるだろう? Is the singer saying, "there may be nights where we'll end up hurting each other," or is he saying, "there may be nights where I'll end up hurting you?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reviewing the song, I've completely flipped on my answer.  The whole song is definitely from his perspective, and this part is definitely him saying he might hurt her feelings.

Original Answer:

I definitely feel it's the 'each other' one.  It's just saying that there are days they will hurt each other's feelings, and days they won't think the same way.  I expect the rest of the song talks about how good they usually are together, or how much they love each other and it's okay, etc.

Comment: No the song is nothing like that. If you click on the link in my question you can hear the song and see my translation.

Comment: Ohhh, THAT song.  Yeah, I'm totally wrong here.  He's definitely talking about himself only.

I'm editing my answer to reflect this.

Comment: lol, why "THAT" song? Have you heard this already before? How confident are you that this is about hurting her feelings and not something physical?

Comment: Because you've been talking about it lately.  :)

When it comes to prose, my confidence level never goes over 50% for any language!

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be the former.  If it were "each other", it would need to be an 〜合う verb (like the latter), like 傷つけ合う夜 (or with しまう, 傷つけ合ってしまう).

Comment: How likely is it that it's actually the latter but it was written this way because it fit in better?

Answer (score 3):

Seems rather vague to me. "There are nights that hurting will be done". By who, and to whom seems opened ended.

Answer (score 1):

There is no subject to this sentence just as its English counterpart `There might be nights that we will hurt each other` doesn't. But if you rather wanted to know the subject of the relative clause `傷つけてしまう`, then its subject is `we`.

Comment: You are right in that the actor of the action 傷つけてしまう is different from the subject in the sentence 傷つけてしまう夜もあるだろう (and therefore the question is not phrased correctly).  However, it is not exactly correct to say that the sentence 傷つけてしまう夜もあるだろう does not have a subject.  The subject of this sentence is 傷つけてしまう夜.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito The matter is controversial. But I see your point. To be more precise, `傷つけてしまう夜` may be an unaccusative subject (underlying object). But there is also a possibility that it is the predicate, with `ある` being a copula.

Comment: Do you mean that some people view ある in ～がある as a copula?  I did not know that, but if so, I agree that this is controversial.